# RubyGems behind a proxy: InvalidArgument

Tags: ruby, proxy, rubygems

The other question (here: ) had solutions that I tried but they didn't work.

I am behind a proxy at work, and can't figure out how to get RubyGems to work through it.

Here's some output to help:

```
josiah@BOX-OF-DOOOM:/etc$ export HTTP_PROXY=http://jkiehl:supersecret@www-proxy.myproxysdomain.com:80/
josiah@BOX-OF-DOOOM:/etc$ sudo gem i cucumber
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cucumber' (>= 0) in any repository
josiah@BOX-OF-DOOOM:/etc$ sudo gem i -p cucumber
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
    invalid argument: -p cucumber
josiah@BOX-OF-DOOOM:/etc$ sudo gem i -P cucumber
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
    invalid argument: -P 
josiah@BOX-OF-DOOOM:/etc$ sudo gem i --http-proxy cucumber
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
```

Any ideas?  I'm baffled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the proxy URL as the `--http-proxy` argument.

```
sudo gem install --http-proxy http://jkiehl:supersecret@www-proxy.myproxysdomain.com:80 cucumber
```

Comment: I thought it operated on the HTTP_PROXY var...  Thanks so much!

Comment: it seems that it needs the scheme as shown in this answer, I tried `--http-proxy somebox` that did not work but this did: `--http-proxy http://somebox`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to set the environment variable HTTP_PROXY, just make sure that when u declare it you ommit the http:// in the proxy url so the line will look like this

set `HTTP_PROXY = username:password@yourproxy:port`

Hope this helps